# JavaScript Date toISOString returns unexpected result before April 3rd, 1978

Tags: javascript, toisostring

When I try the following code in my JS console, it returns the right UTC notation (-2 hours):

```
new Date('1978/04/03').toISOString()
-> "1978-04-02T22:00:00.000Z"
```

However, starting from April 2nd and earlier, it shows a different behaviour: it will only substract 1 hour instead of 2:

```
new Date('1978/04/02').toISOString()
-> "1978-04-01T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Comment: I'd bet it's daylight savings.

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: Yep, Checking https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/1978.html shows some european contries switching to daylight savings on Sunday 2nd April 1978

Answer (score 1):

Odds are it's daylight savings time kicking in, but note that your input format (`yyyy/mm/dd`) is not officially supported, which means that by relying on it you're relying on *"...any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats..."* that the JavaScript engine happens to support, which vary from engine to engine (e.g., browser to browser). If you have a format that isn't [the official supported format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format), you're best off parsing it yourself.

But I suspect you'll find that even `new Date(1978, 3, 3)` and `new Date(1978, 3, 2)` have that one-hour difference, since your JavaScript engine seemed to be parsing that string.